# Jquery simple email validation

Tags: jquery, html

started learning jquery/js/html/css a week ago. We have to create a basic one page website, one feature is validation. Since we arent allowed to use other languages or any form of storage, i have a simple form which doesnt store the data, simply needs to validate it.

```
<form id="frm-contact">
    Full name: <input type="text" name="contact-name"> <br>
    Email Address: <input type="text" name="contact-email" > <br>
    Mobile No:<input type="tel" name="contact-tel"> </br>
    <button type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

```js
$("#btn-submit").click() {
  var text = $('input[type="text"][name=contact-email]').val();
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  //check input against regex - if passes - alert saying "well be in touch soon"
  //else "please insert valid email
  //repeat until valid


}
```

```html
<form id="frm-contact">
  Full name:
  <input type="text" name="contact-name">
  <br>Email Address:
  <input type="text" name="contact-email">
  <br>Mobile No:
  <input type="tel" name="contact-tel">
  </br>
  <button type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn">Submit</button>

</form>
```

jsfiddle response would be much appreciated!!
First post on here so thank you to anyone who answers

Comment: Hi Andy, what exactly is your question here? It looks like you're all set to do the validation. Your next step would be to learn how to use that regular expression against your provided email value.

Comment: thats the bit ive been trying to do and getting no where :( i know it returns a true or false depending on if it passes... just cant figure out how to use that returned value?

Comment: and we arent allowed to use any form of tools or plugins unfortunately

Comment: The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is a great place to see examples of how to use all sorts of features. You would use the returned value to determine `if` you should display an `alert` message.

Comment: There is no need to use any plugin or external code here. I don't think I'm understanding where you have having troubles.

Comment: the jquery part... i have been trying different examples all day and im getting no luck with them... but okay ill have a look at it now thankyou

Comment: Take a look at the place where you define your `click` function. You have a syntax error. If you look at some [examples](https://api.jquery.com/click/) from the jquery documentation, you'll see the correct form that these functions need to take.

Comment: You also might want to open your chrome/firefox developer tools - these errors will be displayed there so you'll have a clue as to where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in your code .Syntax error in your click function

Your regular expression for email validation is not valid too

check the following snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $('input[name=contact-email]').val();
    var re = "/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/";

    //check input against regex - if passes - alert saying "well be in touch soon"
    //else "please insert valid email
    //repeat until valid
    if (text.match(re))
      alert("will be in touch soon");
    else
      alert("invalid email")

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm-contact">
  Full name:
  <input type="text" name="contact-name">
  <br>Email Address:
  <input type="text" name="contact-email">
  <br>Mobile No:
  <input type="tel" name="contact-tel">

  <button type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't re-invent form validation.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation

Comment: This has seemed to helped, thankyou. however its still saying invalid email when i enter my valid email?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimince/w9m34afa/
```

You can have a loook this lovely form submit that I have made ready for you:)

```
function isUsernamePresent() { return $username.val().length > 0; }


function isPasswordValid() {
  return $password.val().length > 2;
}

function arePasswordsMatching() {
  return $password.val() === $confirmPassword.val();
}

function canSubmit() {
  return isPasswordValid() && arePasswordsMatching() && isUsernamePresent();
}

function passwordEvent(){
    //Find out if password is valid  
    if(isPasswordValid()) {
      //Hide hint if valid
      $password.next().hide();
    } else {
      //else show hint
      $password.next().show();
    }
}

function confirmPasswordEvent() {
  //Find out if password and confirmation match
  if(arePasswordsMatching()) {
    //Hide hint if match
    $confirmPassword.next().hide();
  } else {
    //else show hint 
    $confirmPassword.next().show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't re-invent form validation.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent client-side form validation.  There are standards for this.  In fact, e-mail is built-in.

Then, you can use `checkValidity()`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation

Comment: Im not, i found this out very early, however we get the marks for doing it in jquery

Comment: @Andy Whomever tells you that you have to do this in jQuery is wrong.  You should always do things in the best way.  If you have some professor that says otherwise, tell them they're wrong and go learn from somewhere else.  Even for browsers that don't support the new field types, they automatically fall-back to text, and there are good well-tested polyfills.